# context variable received from node js to watson assistant

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson

I am able to receive a context variable $name from the backend(nodejs), and watson assistant is able to print the value. But when watson go to another child node$name is changing to null. What could be the problem ?

Comment: You need a lot more details to clarify the issue. Are you using stateful or stateless connection? Are you using V1 or V2 api? Do you have any sample you can show (that only shows the issue).

Answer (score 0):

Context variables will stay set in the context until your dialog or application resets them. This reset could be in done in anyone off a number of ways.

Your backend application could be creating a fresh context, it could be resetting the variable, unsetting it or setting it to a null value.

Your dialog could be resetting the value. This kind of reset is normally performed by a dialog in a node before it is expecting to read a new value, or in a node after it has processed the value.